# How to find Estimote beacon type?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, estimote

I have searched a lot but end up with no solution. I want to find the type of my Estimote beacon whether `Estimote proximity beacon` or `Estimote indoor location beacon`. The beacons are bought by my client and so I don't known its type. I am trying to create an app with Indoor location beacon, but I'm facing issue by saying **Trying to use proximity beacon** when doing floor mapping process using `Estimote indoor app`. But I asked my client to buy Estimote indoor location only. I have followed all procedure which is in `Estimote docs` for indoor mapping.

Do we have any way to find my beacon type?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically over the air?  Or are you trying to do this just be looking at them?

Comment: Is there any way to find programmatically?! @davidgyoung